# Why does my Makefile pattern rule run its recipe multiple times?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

As per [the gnu make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html#Pattern-Intro), a pattern rule's "...recipe is executed only once to make all the targets." However, I have the following Makefile

```
.PHONY: entrypoint
entrypoint: test_1.cpp test_2.cpp

test_%.cpp:
    echo $@
```

And running `make` produces:

```
echo test_1.cpp
test_1.cpp
echo test_2.cpp
test_2.cpp
```

I'm new to make, and I'm probably misunderstanding something, but the documentation seems misleading if clear.

```
$ make -v
GNU Make 4.0
...
```

Comment: Where do you see the "multiple times"? Also, your recipe isn't making the target, which will lead to a re-execution of the recipe every time, as long as there are no test_1.cpp and test_2.cpp present.

Comment: The output indicates that echo is being invoked twice-once for each file. This is a minimal reproduction, so re-execution isn't the concern here.

Comment: `echo test_1.cpp` is not the output of the `echo` command but the output of make itself - by default the shell echos everything it is executing. This is more or less as if you had typed it on the console. You can suppress this behaviour by pegging a `@` in front of every shell line: `@echo $@`

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of this post. The command that I'm running, and its output are irrelevant. All that matters is that its running the recipe multiple times.

Comment: As your output indicates, it is not - it seems you missed the point by giving an irrelevant example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misreading the documentation.  It means, the recipe is run only one time assuming that all the target patterns in that rule will be created.

Since you have only one target pattern in your rule (test_%.cpp`) make knows that each time it runs that recipe it will create one output file matching that pattern.  To create different targets that match that pattern it will run multiple instances of the recipe.

If you had a rule like this:

```
%.x %.y %.z :
        dothings
```

then make would expect that a single invocation of the recipe `dothings` would create all the targets matching this pattern (e.g., `foo.x`, `foo.y`, and `foo.z`).

Contrast this with an explicit rule like this:

```
foo.x foo.y foo.z :
        dothings
```

Make here treats this exactly as if you'd written this:

```
foo.x :
        dothings
foo.y :
        dothings
foo.z :
        dothings
```

That is, to build all three of these targets it would run the recipe three times.

There's no way to tell make "please run this recipe one time and it will produce every single target that could possibly match the pattern `foo_%.cpp`".

Comment: Is there a way to tell make "please run this recipe one time and it will produce every single target foo.x foo.y and foo.z?" I have a list of file names, and I just want to run a command to generate all of them exactly once.

Comment: I found this: https://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/rules-multiple-outputs-gnu-make

Comment: You can use sentinel files (I guess that crossroads article calls them "dummy files").  That's about the only way.

Comment: If one rule produces multiple outputs AND you can guarantee that no single of those outputs gets deleted/outdated while the other ones are not, then any one of these files serves as target. Make will not care if your recipe produces more than one output (in fact many recipes do produce secondary output e.g. a compiler) as long as the dependency is satisfied.

Comment: Note also that `$@` can have any value in such a rule, depending on which specific target was requested. Using `$*` and then manually appending the suffix is the way to go in the body of such a rule. See https://github.com/o11c/parser-demo/blob/master/Makefile#L19

Answer (score 0):

The following functions construct a dynamic list of dependencies of your multiple-target where the non-existent files are named last. This is more or less the method named "Another attempt" in the link you gave, except that it doesn't trip over missing files and is able to make a missing file by giving it as target on the command line. What it does not: execute the multitarget recipe if one of the multitargets is out of date relative to the others, but I think this is more of wanted side effect than a problem. The only drawback is the syntactic ugliness as you have to write it into an eval expression which forces you to quote all variables in the recipe which shall be evaluated at execution time.

```
define newline :=


endef
list2rules = $(firstword $1) $(if $(word 2,$1),: $(word 2,$1)$(newline)$(call list2rules,$(wordlist 2,1000,$1)))
multitarget = $(call list2rules,$(wildcard $1) $(filter-out $(wildcard $1),$1))

.PHONY: all

targets = test1 test2 footest3
#$(info $(call multitarget,$(targets)))

all: somefile

somefile: $(targets)
    touch somefile

# here we generate the dependency list on the spot. Only one recipe to update all targets.
$(eval $(call multitarget,\
$(targets)) : ; \
    touch $(targets) \
)
```